# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar por categorías en un loop de imágenes en Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

En el custom post type del loop a cada articulo le di sus categorías, pero el problema es  ¿Cómo hago para que filtre sin recargar la pagina o redireccione al apretar un item del menú? he intentado hacerlo usando Jquery siguiendo tutoriales de YouTube y lo único que pude hacer es que si aprieto cualquier item del menu los features se ocultan y si aprieto el primer item se muestran pero no se logra hacer el filtro con las categorías seleccionadas.

```
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item li-item">
                <!-- creamos atributos personalizados -->
                <a class="nav-link active filtro" href="#" aria-current="page" data-categoria="all">All work</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item li-item">
                <a class="nav-link link filtro" href="#" data-categoria="branding">Branding</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item li-item">
                <a class="nav-link link filtro" href="#" data-categoria="marketing">Marketing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item li-item">
                <a class="nav-link link filtro" href="#" data-categoria="planning">Plannig</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item li-item">
                <a class="nav-link link filtro" href="#" data-categoria="research">Research</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

    //este loop lo estoy llamando desde un archivo externo :)
    
    <div class="row">
    <?php
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $post_per_page = 1; 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'features',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    if(have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    
        
            <div class="card carta-features ps-0 pe-0 col-12 col-md-2" style="width: 17rem;">
                <?php abello_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <div class="iconos-features text-center">
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-link fa-2xl"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="ms-4">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass-plus fa-2xl"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        
    
    
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <p class="text-center mb-0">asdOops!, Lo sentimos, no hay contenido que mostrar</p>
    <?php endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    $wp_query = $temp ?>
    </div>

         let boton = $('.filtro');
       boton.click(function(){
            let filtro = $(this).attr('data-categoria');
            if(filtro == 'all'){
                $('.carta-features').show(500);
            }else{
                $('.carta-features').not('.'+filtro).hide(500);
                $('.carta-features').filter('.'+filtro).show(500);
            }
            boton.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
       });
```

Comment: Lo más sencillo que se me ocurre es poner la categoría en la clase, así solo tienes que hacer $("TODOS").hide y $("."+cat).show

Answer (score 0):

Algo tarde pero para contribuir en algo si a alguien le ayuda.

Primera observación, en `card carta-features` no estas incluyendo la clase correspondiente a la categoría de modo que jamás las va a encontrar.

Esto puede quedar así:

```
<div class="card <?= strtolower(get_the_category()[0]->name); ?> carta-features ps-0 pe-0 col-12 col-md-2" style="width: 17rem;">
    // Demás contenido
</div>
```

Después tienes un error tu jquery en el else, .filter() debería ser .show(), pero este debería estar antes del hide para que primero muestre y luego oculte, de lo contrario primero oculta y luego vuele a mostrar todo, esto debería quedar así:

```
if(filtro == 'all'){
    $('.carta-features').show(500);
}else{
    $('.carta-features').show('.'+filtro).show(500);
    $('.carta-features').not('.carta-features.'+filtro).hide(500);
}
```